# Installing the phonegap facebook plugin

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I'm trying to install the phonegap plugin for Facebook by Jos downloadable here: https://github.com/jos3000/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Facebook

I've got the folder structure set up like this:

```
src/com/facebook/android/*.java
src/com/hipsnip/plugins/facebook/FacebookAuth.java
src/com/my_app/app/App.java
libs/phonegap-1.0.0.jar
/res/xml/plugins.xml
assets/www/index.html facebook.js phonegap-1.0.0.js
```

I've added the plugin to the plugin.xml file like so:

```
<plugin name="facebook" value="com.hipsnip.plugins.facebook.FacebookAuth" />
```

I've added the facebook.js to my index.html, and have the following function (which gets triggered by pressing a button):

```
function facebook_login()
{
  var appId = "1234"; // this is your facebook app id change me

  window.plugins.facebook.authorize(appId,function(res){
    alert(res.name);
  });
});
```

});
}

The app opens up a new browser window (I suspect that's what it is) but all it displays is my application without running javascript.
LogCat shows the following error:

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 95 : TypeError: Result of expression 'window.plugins.facebook' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Thanks for any help you can give (I suspect it has to do with the way that I've set up the folders, or the way I've added the plugin.xml, but I really don't have a clue)!

Comment: i think the problem is in opening a new page, you might check into that.

Comment: how do you mean? where would this take place?

Comment: I got Jos' plugin working - with a html/js/css app. In plugins.xml I use: <plugin name="FacebookAuth" value="com.hipsnip.plugins.facebook.FacebookAuth"/>.

Comment: Also, not sure if your javascript is meant to be literal, but from your authorize() you'll get res.token (or not) which his plugin will save for you and use, e.g. in future request()'s. His cascading calls of authorize() --> getAccess() are needed. Let me know if you'd like code examples.

Comment: I got it working in the end, but I had to re-add the PluginMaker which had been removed mid-August (and I know isn't right), was going to answer this question with a proper how-to once I am done with the app. Thanks for the offer though!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576977/is-there-any-facebook-plugin-for-phonegap-2-7-0/16579592#16579592

Answer (score 3):

PhoneGap now has an [official Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin). Use that.