# Is there any Facebook plugin for phonegap 2.7.0?

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, mobile

Is there any Facebook plugin for Phonegap 2.7.0?

When we try the below one, we are end up with deprecated error on Phonegap 2.7.0.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/README.md

We couldn't find anything when we Google it.

Thank you,

Sid

Comment: @Sid-Sid i have apply similar plugin using PhoneGap 2.7.0.It is working for me.May be you have forgot some steps to properly apply plugin in your application.Again go step by on the link you have provided in your question.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use the inappbrowser plugin that comes with phonegap to do this .. example shown below.
Fill in the xxx below with your relevant info

```
var my_client_id = "xxxxxx", // YOUR APP ID
    my_secret = "xxxxxxxxx", // YOUR APP SECRET 
    my_redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html", // LEAVE THIS
    my_type ="user_agent", my_display = "touch"; // LEAVE THIS

var facebook_token = "fbToken"; // OUR TOKEN KEEPER
var ref; //IN APP BROWSER REFERENCE

// FACEBOOK
var Facebook = {
    init:function(){
         // Begin Authorization
         var authorize_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?";
         authorize_url += "client_id=" + my_client_id;
         authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + my_redirect_uri;
         authorize_url += "&display=" + my_display;
         authorize_url += "&scope=publish_stream";

             //CALL IN APP BROWSER WITH THE LINK
         ref = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=no');

         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event){

             Facebook.facebookLocChanged(event.url);

          });

    },
    facebookLocChanged:function(loc){

        if (loc.indexOf("code=") >= 1  ) {

            //CLOSE INAPPBROWSER AND NAVIGATE TO INDEX
            ref.close();

            //THIS IS MEANT TO BE DONE ON SERVER SIDE TO PROTECT CLIENT SECRET
            var codeUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='+my_client_id+'&client_secret='+my_secret+'&redirect_uri='+my_redirect_uri+'&code='+loc.split("=")[1];
            console.log('CODE_URL::' + codeUrl);
            $.ajax({
                url: codeUrl,
                data: {},
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data, status){
                    //WE STORE THE TOKEN HERE
                    localStorage.setItem(facebook_token, data.split('=')[1].split('&')[0]);
                    },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Unknown error Occured");
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
```

I would add more functions for logout and posting to a wall etc.
You can find documenatation on the inappbrowser [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

Comment: Given that it's possible (perhaps even easy?) to get at the source for a PhoneGap app on Android, is it a concern that your facebook app account's secret key is in the code?

Comment: you can see the comment above, should be done at the server side where the app secret is used.