# How do PhoneGap applications typically handle user accounts?

Tags: facebook, cordova, oauth-2.0, user-accounts, phonegap-build

At the risk of having -1s rain down on me for this question, I'm going to ask anyway.  I am playing with PhoneGap, and for my application, user accounts are optional, but recommended.  I don't have any web experience, so I don't know the most secure way to deal with stuff like this.

I can think of three options:

1. Facebook login
2. Google login
3. Roll my own

From what I've read online, the Facebook plugin for PhoneGap is only for "facebook apps", which my app is not.  Regarding Google, everything points to using OAuth, which I am entirely unfamiliar with.  So that seems to leave #3 as the only other option.

If the masters of PhoneGap apps here believe #3 is the way to go, would you be able to recommend any references?  I have been looking all over and have come up short.  Ok, correction, I did find [one reference](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap) so far, but more is better!

Comment: Option 1. is the best; you can use facebook just for authentication
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576977/is-there-any-facebook-plugin-for-phonegap-2-7-0/16579592#16579592

Comment: @ClintonWard thanks!  I have posted a followup comment to your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but if you ever decide to go with option 3, you might want to try [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users) (which also supports Facebook logins).  I've successfully used it with PhoneGap, and there's a [tutorial by Raymond Camden](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/using-parse-with-phonegap-a-marriage-made-in-awesome.html) that may help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!  I have read one of Raymond's other posts that deals with logins, but decided against that since it didn't use https.  I'll look at that link as well.